# Combine two ffmpeg commands to encode, watermark, and subtitle a file

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, convert

How to integrate these two commands so I only need to run one?

I want to add watermark, encode the quality and add a subtitle all with one command.

Encode and watermark:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:360[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=10:10" -tune psnr -refs 3 -c:v libx265 -preset veryslow -crf 33 videofull.mp4
```

Add subtitle:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter:v subtitles=text.srt videosub.mp4
```

How can I combine the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:360[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=10:10,subtitles=text.srt" -c:v libx265 -preset veryslow -crf 33 videofull.mp4
```

Filters in the same linear chain are separated by commas, and distinct linear chains of filters are separated by semicolons. See [FFmpeg Filtering Introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) for more info.

I removed `-tune psnr -refs 3` because psnr is detrimental for general encoding and refs should be covered by the preset.